# How do I compare the relationship between three variables where one variable is dependent on the other two?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have three physical variables say x, y and z. The magnitude of y is dependent on x (directly proportional), and y is dependent on z (inversely proportional). x and z don't have any relationship (z is a measurement point).

For example (some of my data)

[image]

I am interested in producing a model that describes their relationship and I am unsure about how to approach that (attached is a plot of the data).

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some plots? For ex a pairs plot?

Comment: yes, here's a plot for the above data

Comment: Is z bounded between 0 and 1? Is y bounded from below by 0? Do you have any domain knowledge what this relationship should be like?